# How to show holomorphic de Rham complex is exact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Supppse $X$ is a smooth algebraic manifold, how does one show the holomorphic de Rham complex is exact in characteristic $0$?

I knew a method is to resolve it by double complex $A^{p,q}$, then the column exactness shows it is quasi isomorphic to differential de Rham complex, thus exact. But this method is transcendental, is there a algebraic way of showing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of a lot of interpretations of this question. Let $X$ be an algebraic manifold. Here are things which I could imagine "the holomorphic de Rham complex is exact" meaning.

**The complex $\mathcal{O} \to \Omega^1 \to \Omega^2 \to \cdots$ is exact, where $\Omega^p$ is the algebraic $p$-forms.** This isn't true. Take $X = \{ z : z \neq 0 \}$. Then $dz/z$ is a closed $1$-form which is not exact.

**The complex $\mathcal{O} \to \Omega^1 \to \Omega^2 \to \cdots$ is exact, where $\Omega^p$ is the holomorphic $p$-forms.** This is also false; the same counterexample works.

**The complex of sheaves $\mathcal{O} \to \Omega^1 \to \Omega^2 \to \cdots$ is exact in the Zariski topology, for either of the options above** Again false: $dz/z$ does not become exact on any Zariski open.

**The complex of sheaves $\mathcal{O} \to \Omega^1 \to \Omega^2 \to \cdots$ is exact in the analytic topology, where $\Omega^p$ is the holomorphic $p$-forms**. This is a true theorem. It's pretty intrinsically an analytic result though; it uses analytic topology and holomorphic functions. You don't need to go to $(p,q)$ forms to do it though. Here is a proof that stays purely in the holomorphic world. On a formal level, this is exactly the same proof (or a same proof, anyway) as in the smooth real function case.

We will show that $\mathcal{O} \to \Omega^1 \to \Omega^2 \to \cdots$ is exact on any polydisc $\{ (z_1, \ldots, z_n) : |z_i| < r_i \}$, where $\Omega^p$ is the holomorphic $p$-forms. Any complex manifold obviously has a basis of open sets which are polydiscs, so this is enough.

We prove the following statement by induction on $k$: Let 
$$\omega = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_p \leq k} f_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_p}(z_1, \ldots, z_n)\  d z_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge d z_{i_p}$$
be a closed holomorphic $p$-form. Then $\omega$ is $d \eta$ for some holomorphic $p$-form $\eta$. Note that $k$ appears in the subscript of the summation, and the number of variables is $n$.

The base case $k=0$ (or $k < p$ more generally) is trivial; $\omega$ must be zero.

Now, we do the inductive case. The equation $d \omega=0$ implies that, for $j>k$, we have $\partial f_{i_1 \cdots i_p}(z_1, \ldots, z_n)/\partial z_j=0$. So the $f_{i_1 \cdots i_p}$ functions only depend on $(z_1, \ldots, z_k)$ and we will write them as $f_{i_1 \cdots i_p}(z_1, \ldots, z_k)$ from now on.

Set $\phi = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_{p-1} < k} dz_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge d z_{i_{p-1}} \int_{t=0}^{z_k} f_{i_1 \cdots i_{p-1} k}(z_1, \ldots, z_{k-1}, t) dt.$ (The integral is along any path through the disc $|t|<r_k$.)
Then $\omega - d \phi$ has no $dz_k$ terms. So, by induction, $\omega - d \phi = d \psi$ for some $\psi$, and $\omega = d(\phi+\psi)$.

**The de Rham complex of formal power series, or on polynomials, is exact** This is true. You can copy the above proof, but my preferred argument is the following: Put a $\mathbb{Z}^n$ grading on polynomial differential forms, where $z_i$ and $dz_i$ are in degree $(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$, with the $1$ in the $i$-th place. So $d$ preserves the degree. Then the complex breaks up into a direct sum (direct product for power series) of finite dimensional complexes, one each degree.

The complex in degree $(k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n)$ is the tensor product of $n$ complexes that look like $\mathbb{R} \overset{k_i}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{R}$ if $k_i > 0$, or $\mathbb{R} \to 0$ if $k_i=0$. This complex is exact if any of the $k_i$ are $>0$. So the only cohomology comes from the degree $(0,0,\ldots,0)$ complex, which is all in $H^0$.

Comment: It is a really nice answer! (to my ill posed question..) One thing confused me, what do you mean by de Rham complex on polynomials in your final remark?

Comment: Differential forms of the form $\sum f_{i_1 \cdots i_p}(z_1,\ldots, z_n) dz_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dz_{i_p}$ where the $f_{i_1 \cdots i_p}$ are polynomials.

Comment: By the first example, algebraic de Rham complex is not exact at every stalk, so it is not exact at the completion of each local ring, by faithful flatness of completion. But it is exact on analytic local ring. Taking completion we get exactness at completion of every local ring. Where did I made a mistake?

Comment: Since $d$ is not a map of modules, the result on faithful flatness you are using is not applicable.

Comment: By polynomial case you mean de Rham complex is exact on affine space?

Comment: Yes (plus extra padding.)

Comment: In general, if you consider a triangulated manifold and look at the cdga of power series polynomial differential forms, how does the cohomology of this cochain complex compare to the cohomology of the (non power series) polynomial differential forms?